# What does the SQL standard say about "dependent" conditionals in UPDATE?

Tags: sql, standards

Can anyone tell me what the result to the following should be according to the standard (a reference to the correct part of the standard would be welcome)

```
> select * from t1;
+------+
| col1 |
+------+
|    9 |
|    8 |
|   10 |
+------+
> update t1
    set col1 = col1 * 2
    where col1 <= (select avg(col1) from t1);
```

The point is: Does the last row get updated, since if the rows are updated in order and the average is recalculated for each row, it will satisfy the condition, or does it not get updated because any data changed by this statement will only be readable after the whole statement ran?

**EDIT**
And what about this case?

```
> select * from t1;
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 |
+------+------+
|    9 |    1 |
|    8 |    2 |
|   10 |    2 |
+------+------+
> update t1 p1
    set col1 = col1 * 2
    where col1 <= (select avg(col1)
                     from t1
                     where col2=p1.col2);
```

Comment: Here the subquery executed first. So average doesn't not change.

Comment: @Shiplu Thank you. And what about this second case, where the subquery can't be pre-executed?

Comment: @baruch - It can be pre-executed in that a separate read operation identifies the rows to be updated and stores the row identifiers in a spool or similar then the update is done reading from that spool after the read is finished. That is the plan I would expect in SQL Server. Not sure I can be bothered digging through the SQL Standard to find the relevant bits though. A couple of related concepts are "all–at–once operations" and halloween protection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the standard (Chapter 14.11, SQL 2003 - Foundation) is pretty clear about this:

> *The  is effectively evaluated for each row of T **before** any row of T is updated*

(emphasis mine)

My understanding of that sentence is that *any* condition (whether co-related or not) is evaluated before any row is updated.

Comment: ... and one popular (if not the only DBMS) that does NOT conform with the standard - and similar to the examples queries may result in non-standard results - is MySQL.

Comment: @ypercube: why am I not surprised?

Comment: To be honest, this is one of the most serious, if not the most serious, deviation from the standards. Even simple `UPDATE t SET id = id + 1` are done in serial manner and not as a set operation, and will result in PK violations.

Comment: @ypercube: there is also the case of deleting rows from a self referencing table: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b05b1/1 works fine in Oracle, PostgreSQL and others, but not in MySQL. btw: the `id = id + 1` only works in Postgres sincd 9.0 and deferrable unique constraint

Answer (score 3):

About the first query, the `subquery` executed first so, there is no changes in average...

About second query, you are using alias in `UPDATE` statement but you are using alias in wrong approach.

Correct and Standard way to use alias in `UPDATE` statement is:

```
UPDATE p1
     set col1 = col1 * 2
from t1 p1
     where col1 <= (select avg(col1)
                     from t1
                     where col2=p1.col2);
```

Comment: The SQL standard does not allow a `FROM` clause for an `UPDATE` statement. So your example is not "the standard way". Additionally in the SQL standard the table alias is defined in the `UPDATE` part: `UPDATE <target table> [ [ AS ] <correlation name> ]`. The above syntax is only valid for MySQL if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @ a_horse_with_no_name:Thank you....It works on MS-SQL Server..I have already tested above query in MSSQL But when I execute OP's second query, it throws error...

Comment: Check the behaviour of SQL-Server in Data Exchange: [SQL standard and dependent conditionals in UPDATE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/65653/sql-standard-and-dependent-conditionals-in-update)

Answer (score 2):

The last row would not get updated.
because "select avg(col1) from t1" is a sub-query, and it will run firstly, and store the result in the temporary table, then the update statement will execute.